# How can I enable ip_forward in Android?

Tags: android

I'm testing arp spoofing on phone but it's not working. ARP is changed on my PC but after it i can't ping any website.

I did this on phone:

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

And after cat all seems good but after arp spoofing i can't connect to the internet from PC.

I did this same on PC and on PC is working but I want to do this on phone.

How can I achieve this?

Software on phone:

Android 4.4.4

Kernel: 3.4.67

Xperia E4.

Comment: Did you use the phone as WiFI hotspot or usb tether? I assume you were using something like Linux deploy/chroot and not natively installed linux? I assume you modified the phone's core system /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward meaning you needed root, as opposed to the Linux chroot one right?

Answer (score 1):

I had fixed it!

I'm using these three commands and now it's working.

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -F -t filter

iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

And now it's working :)